# Is it possible to listen for changes from the DOM in the server using Cheerio.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to trigger a function in the server when a change happen in the DOM.

```
var $ = cheerio.load('<span class="ready">WE ARE ALMOST READY!</span>');
$.html();

var textDeploy = $('.ready').text();
console.log(textDeploy);

if ( textDeploy != "WE ARE ALMOST READY!"){
  console.log("send email");
} else {
  console.log("not ready to send the email");
}
```

I'm logging "not ready to send the email" in the terminal, but when I change the text at the span ('.ready') to any other text doesn't seem that cheerio is listening to the changes. Is it possible to listen for changes? or any other convenient way? Thanks!

Comment: the question is not pretty clear that what you want to listen about, it seems you want to listen a change in server side and then want t update any dom component test. better to go for a WebSocket model, if your server  support it, otherwise better to make a continuous lookup from client side (may be ajax call in interval or initiate new ajax call when the last call is done resoled/rejected/error)

Comment: I want to listen a change from the client side ( new innerText of a span tag when a button is clicked ) in the server side. I'm current accessing to the text when the DOM is loaded but not when the span text is changed. I'm going to take a look for a WebSocket, thanks!